# Registry change on a key a server does not have

Tags: windows, group-policy, iscsi, windows-registry

I have written a script that queries the registry on multiple servers looking for specific keys (dealing with iSCSI). After the query, I need to make changes to some of the keys in:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{GUID}\(instanceID)\parameters
```

My plan is to make a Group Policy that will change this across the board.

My question has a few parts:

1. Are the GUIDs from `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\control\class` determined from the driver? For example, would the same GUID number for iSCSI be on all Windows boxes? or would it be the same for Windows 2008 and a separate one for 2003?
2. The GUIDs contain different instance IDs (0000, 0001, etc). If I make the changes in every instance, would that matter?
3. If I add the keys on systems that don't have these keys, would performance be affected?

I am sorry for the multiple questions, and if that is too many for one post, then consider this as a single, concise question:

Can I change the aforementioned keys across an entire network without introducing problems?

Comment: `Can I change the aforementioned keys across an entire network without introducing problems?`  The answer is **always** "no, you need to do testing first."

Comment: Correct. It was an over-simplification. I am really looking for specific information on those keys I guess. I'll do some testing and post my results in an answer.